# Heroku Twitter Streaming API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have an app that:

1. Has an always running process which is connected to Twitter's Streaming API, which constantly accepts data, manipulates it, and saves to the db
2. There is also a web service that serves pages, and also uses the db

Now my question is, **how do I use heroku effectively in this case?**

What I understand is:

1. Use a worker dyno to execute your background jobs
2. Don't use the scheduler to run long-running jobs
3. I can still have everything in 1 app if I have a web dyno serving up my pages and worker dynos to execute my job

Is a forever running process considered a "background job"?  It doesn't really belong in a queue, since it should *always* be running.  What am I missing here?  What is the best way to go about this on heroku?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use a evented server such as `thin` to handle streaming. here is a guide

> Pulling in tweets with the Twitter Streaming API with web applications
>   can be a challenge. Adam Wiggins of Heroku discussed a way to consume
>   the API with EventMachine. Another post described using this method
>   with thin and sinatra. I decided to take it one step further and
>   created a demo application that you can deploy on Heroku and use
>   MongoDB for fast and efficient storage.

see for more info: http://joslynesser.com/blog/archives/2010/09/12/consuming-the-twitter-streaming-api-with-heroku-and-mongodb/